# new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear()) returns a 13 digit number

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, electron

When using `var years = new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear())` I am getting a 13-digit number in return. (`1521150199880`)

The entire code block is as follows:

```
function changeYear(value) {
var years = new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear());
alert(years)
if (value < 0) {
year1 = year1 - 1;
document.getElementById("barText").innerHTML = years;
} else if(value > 0) {
years = years + 1;
document.getElementById("barText").innerHTML = years;
} else {
alert("Error!");
}
}
```

The program subtracts the year by one if the `value` input of the function is negative, and opposite for any other cases (Except when the `value` input is == 0, obviously)

Anyone see the problem? I have also tried exchanginf `.getFullYear()` with `.getYear()` without luck :/

Comment: [`getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setFullYear) returns "The number of milliseconds between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the updated date."

Comment: A Date object's value is the number of milliseconds since midnight 1 Jan 1970 UTC. That's what the digits are, and they are returned because that's [the return value of `setFullYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setFullYear).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

setFullYear() returns *The number of milliseconds between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the updated date*.

For your code to work

Replace this line

```
var years = new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear());
```

with this

```
var years = new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear())).getFullYear(); //as you want year from here
```

I don't know why you are doing this as `new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear())).getFullYear()` equals to `new Date().getFullYear()`. So you can also do this

```
  var years = new Date().getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 1):

The value for Date object is the number of milliseconds since midnight 1 Jan 1970 UTC.

Replace this line

```
var years = new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear());
```

with this

```
var years = new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear()));
```

Comment: Care to explain why?